# Solve a the following whodunnit problem using graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

There are 7 suspects: **A, O L, D, B, C, S.** They all visited the castle where the crime was committed. The one who has the most visits is the criminal.
They were asked with whom they met at the castle and they answered in the following way:

A: O, L, B, C.

O: A, L, D, B, S.

L: A, O, D.

D: O, L, B.

B: A, O, D, S.

C: A, S.

S: O, B, C.

I made the following graph:[image]

I tried to think of the possible days they visited the castle. I said that if X and Y saw each other, then they visited the castle on the same day.
Then, we have:

day 1: {C,S}

day 2: {C,A}

day 3: {S,O,B}

day 4: {A,B,O}

day 5: {O,B,D}

day 6: {L,D,O}

day 7: {A,O,L}

Based on this, O has the most visits and it is the criminal. However, from some days I could leave out O and that would change the result.

Is what I did correct or is my reasoning correct? If not, where was I wrong?

Comment: It seems to be about right. There is one issue I have with the initial question: What prevents for example A, B to visit the castle five times independently? It would do nothing to change the graph/line of reasoning while it would change the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rather a puzzle for [PSO](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com) than algorithm question.

I believe, the suspects' answers are unique: it means A met O exactly **one** time. Otherwise it makes no sense as it could be any number.

To solve the puzzle, I created a script, which takes an array of the suspect visits and for each visit XYZ creates records like `X: YZ`, `Y: XZ` and `Z: XY` (order does matter).

Using the script I found out, that your visit scheme is not lead to the suspects' answers. Then I created my own, played with the order a bit, and finally I got almost 100% result (slightly different order for B answers):

```
A: O, L, B, C
O: A, L, D, B, S
L: A, O, D
D: O, L, B
B: A, D, O, S
C: A, S
S: O, B, C
```

It looks like **A is the criminal** with **4 visits**.The script sources:

```rb
visits = %w[
  AO
  AL
  OLD
  BA
  CA
  BD
  OBS
  CS
]
result = {}
visits.each do |visit|
  chars = visit.chars
  chars.each do |char|
    result[char] ||= []
    result[char] += chars - [char]
  end
end
result.each do |k, v|
  puts '%s: %s' % [k, v.join(', ')]
end
```

You can play with the code [here](https://ideone.com/RBMSKm).
As example, [your visits scheme](https://ideone.com/AzX1Y6) produces following suspects' answers:

```
C: S, A
S: C, O, B
A: C, B, O, O, L
O: S, B, A, B, B, D, L, D, A, L
B: S, O, A, O, O, D
D: O, B, L, O
L: D, O, A, O
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I understand now thanks to you